# How to group grep results by seconds

Tags: language-agnostic

I have the following in a log file,

01:31:01,222 Received event
 
01:31:01,435 Received event
01:31:01,441 Received event
 
01:31:01,587 Received event
 
01:31:02,110 Received event
 
01:31:02,650 Received event
 
01:31:02,869 Received event
 
01:31:03,034 Received event
 
01:31:03,222 Received event

I would like to group this by seconds and count the number of lines in each group to output the following,

01:31:01 4
01:31:02 3
01:31:03 2

Ideally I like to do this in a simple awk script without having to resort to perl or python, any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{a[$1]++}END{for(i in a){print i, a[i]}}' file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
01:31:01 4
01:31:02 3
01:31:03 2
```

**Explanation:**

I'm using the option `-F` (field separator) and set it to `,`. This makes it easy to obtain the time with seconds accuracy in field 1 (`$1`).

Explanation of the script itself (in a multiline form):

```
# Runs on every line and increments a count tied to the first field (the time)
# (The associative array a will get created on first access)
{a[$1]++}

# Runs after all lines have been processed. Iterates trough the array 'a' and prints
# each key (time) and its associated value (count)
END {
    for(i in a){
        print i, a[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: super quick and precise

Comment: sorry it was misleading in my first post, please see the updated text. I'm not sure if this will still work.

Comment: @liaaba Have you tried it? I did, and it worked. Why it is not working for you?

Comment: @hek2mgl I posted that before your edit and edited my comment after I saw your edit, somehow it didn't get saved...but it's working now and already marked it as the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the output order, you can just do:

```
cut -d, -f1 file|uniq -c
```

(with a |sort before |uniq if the data isn't always sorted initially).

Produces:

```
      4 01:31:01
      3 01:31:02
      2 01:31:03
```